# Local Iphone App Storage using Jquery Mobile & Cordova & ColdFusion CFC

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios7, coldfusion, cordova-3

The use of the app:

The app connects to my tracking server and reports the locations of specific users who are wearing one of my tracking devices and the devices are reporting their locations to the tracking server.

The above is working in the app I have set up connectivity to CFC's that query the database based on the imei number being passed to the CFC via the app and it returns a list of the latest locations ALL GOOD

Now I am looking at adding some privacy / security measures

The account holder for each device is assigned admin rights allowing that person to add app users to the system, this means registering their name, email address which is stored in the app users table along with the admin users id and also the imei number of the device the admin user is giving the app user access to. At the time the new record is recorded in the database table it also records a unique 16 character access code which is recorded in the access_code field for that record. and then the system generates an email to the app user advising them their have been given access to the Persons x's tracker and also provides them with the access code. The user simply downloads the app from the app store installs the app and enters the access code. The access code then needs to be stored as local storage on the device, so its remains in place even after a device reboot.

Then when the app devices page loads it takes the access codes stored in local storage and uses those values (of which potentially their may be several as one app user may be granted access to several different tracking devices ) and queries the cfc passing those stored access codes to the cfc to generate a list of matching devices in the table.

The hole purpose of the above is so that the admin of the device (they the only ones able to grant app access to a specific tracker data ) can is necessary delete the record of any user they have previously given access to in the manner described above which will then automatically prevent that user from being able to view a specific device as even though the user may still have the unique access code stored on their app in local storage for a given device that record will have been deleted in the table of users by the admin therefore preventing that user from being able to see the location details of the specific user. (eg staff member of a age care facility has the app downloaded on their personal phone and that staff member resigns or the person being tracked is now moved to another facility eliminating the need for that staff member to able to access the location details of the patient)

So now to my question

what's the easiest and simplest way to be able to have the staff member enter the access code that has been sent to them so that it records in local storage on the device (remaining presented even after a reboot of the device) and to be able to potentially have multiple access codes loaded into local storage for different devices so that each time the devices page is loaded in the app all the access codes in local storage are passed to the cfc to be used in the query that outputs the list of matched devices.

I do hope the above make sense and I have not made the topic too long winded and or confusing

Comment: So you need simple data, an access code, stored locally to a device?

Comment: Also, are you using phonegap?

Comment: Yes correct 

The user has a firm to submit which contains an access code which they need to enter I to the form.

This value is stored locally on the device and remains in place even after device  reboot

Each time the app loads it reads the the valu or values stores locally which it passes to the coldfusion cfc on the survey to return the matching details for each access code that have been stored locally

And yes i am using phone gap cordova

Comment: Have you looked at the phonegap API for this? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html